# Concurrency Handling In Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-java

I implemented a Prometheus Histogram to calculate response time and tried to send 10 concurrent requests.

Here does one request close the timer opened by another request in Prometheus.
request 1 enters at t1
reqest2 enters at t2
request1 finishes at t3
But request1 close the counter started by requests measuring the  response time as t3-t2
when it is actually t3-t1

Is this handled by Prometheus Instrumentation Library ? I use Java for instrumentation.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @JellyFilledNuts I use Java.